# What is the minimum space complexity in problem of find longest common substring?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

```
const char *_longest_common_substr(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n, int m) {
   // assert n >= m
   int max = 0; // keep track of max length found
   int tmp = 0; // value is incremented till letters match
   int begin = 0;
   int try_begin = 0; // possible new begin index
   int end = 0; // rv = s2[begin : end - 1]
   
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       tmp = 0;
       try_begin = 0;
       // s1 is scanned circularly
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           int index = (j + i) % n; // current s1 index
           if (index < n && s1[index] == s2[j]) {
               if (tmp == 0)
                   try_begin = j;
               tmp++;
           } else {
               tmp = 0;
           }
           if (tmp > max) {
               max = tmp;
               begin = try_begin;
               end = j + 1;
           }
       }
   }
       
   int size = begin >= end ? 0 : end - begin;
   char *rv = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*rv));
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
       rv[i] = s2[begin + i];
   rv[i] = '\0';
   return rv;
}

const char *longest_common_substr(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n, int m) {
   if (n < m)
       return _longest_common_substr(s2, s1, m, n);
   return _longest_common_substr(s1, s2, n, m);
}
```

Is this code correct to find longest common substring? I don't understand why in many places, for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Dynamic_programming), they use a matrix to solve the problem, while in this apparently simple solution there is no need for it and time complexity is still **O(n*m)** while space complexity is **O(1)**.
A possible test is

```
int main() {
    const char *str1 = "identification";
    const char *str2 = "administration";
    
    printf("%s\n", longest_common_substr(str1, str2, strlen(str1), strlen(str2)));
    
}
```

and the output is

```
ation
```

substring is intended in a circular way, so with input

```
action
tionac
```

the output will be

```
tionac
```

anyway i could add two different invalid character at the end of the strings to remove this property

Comment: *Is this code correct*. You should try to answer that yourself by running test cases against the code.

Comment: yes i did it and works

Comment: You need better names for your variables. Your algorithm is difficult to follow

Comment: @bolov i added some comments

Comment: `_longestCommonSubstr` name is reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace in C++. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another name for the function.

Comment: @eeroika updated, however this code is C

Comment: @Jhowa `_longest_common_substr` is also reserved. If this isn't C++, then why is it tagged C++?

Comment: `index < n` is always true in `if (index < n && s1[index] == s2[j])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm performs circular matching, which is different from the classic LCS algorithm. Yet it can be simplified to remove this extra matching and also remove the need to make `s1` the longer string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *longest_common_substr(const char *s1, const char *s2, int n1, int n2) {
    int begin = 0;  // offset of lcs in s2
    int max = 0;    // length of lcs

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        int tmp = 0;        // count of matched letters
        int index = i;      // current s1 index
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++, index++) {
            if (index == n1) {
                index = 0;
                tmp = 0;    // do not match circularly
            }
            if (s1[index] == s2[j]) {
                tmp++;
                if (tmp > max) {
                    max = tmp;
                    begin = j - (tmp - 1);
                }
            } else {
                tmp = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    char *rv = malloc(sizeof(*rv) * (max + 1));
    memcpy(rv, s2 + begin, max);
    rv[max] = '\0';
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        const char *s1 = argv[1];
        const char *s2 = argv[2];
        char *p = longest_common_substr(s1, s2, strlen(s1), strlen(s2));
        if (p) {
            printf("lcs('%s','%s') -> '%s'\n", s1, s2, p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above does have a time complexity of **O(n1*n2)** and a space complexity of **O(1)**. Achieving better time complexity is usually a desired goal, which may explain why the Wikipedia article has a suboptimal example for the more complex case.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is a weird one. You count circular substrings on the longest string only. And if the strings are of equal length you count circular substrings on the first one only.

For instance:

- for `"bxa"` and `"ab"` you find the solution `"ab"` because you count circular substrings on `bxa`
- but for `"bxa"` and `"zaby"` you don't consider circular substrings in `"bxa"` and you don't find `"ab"` as a solution
- `("abx", "bya")` and `("bya", "abx")` have different solutions even though only the position of the arguments changes. (you count circular substrings only on the first argument if both arguments are of equal length).

You must either:

- not count circular substrings at all (the classic algorithm as described in the wiki link) or:
- count circular substrings for both strings (this is a different algorithm then *longest common substring*)

So the complexity of your algorithm is not comparable with the wiki algorithm because it is a different algorithm solving a different problem.

Comment: I could add a different an invalid character at the end of each strings to reset the count, so the problem is the same, or i could exploit '\0' to reset the count